# What is the format of the data in a specified string and how to parse it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, parsing

Can you please tell me what format does this string have:

```
35ba2fdd1178b5883c254cc5470626f3__id|s:4:"1020";35ba2fdd1178b5883c254cc5470626f3__name|s:9:"Test Test";35ba2fdd1178b5883c254cc5470626f3__states|a:0:{}
```

How can I parse it in node.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found myself. It's php session. To parse it, I used php-unserialize from npm.